# How to use hdfs directory path in tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession API for writing logs and checkpoints

Tags: tensorflow

In distributed tensorflow, I am using two different machines as worker servers and one machine as parameter server. Both the worker and parameter servers need access to the shared directory where they can write logs and checkpoints. I planned to use hdfs as a shared folder but its not working. does anyone know what is wrong in the code or anyone knows other options apart from using hdfs as a shared folder. 
    import argparse
    import sys

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf

FLAGS = None

def deepnn(x):
  x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)

h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)

h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2
return y_conv, keep_prob

def conv2d(x, W):
 return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
 return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

def weight_variable(shape):
 initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
 return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
 initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
 return tf.Variable(initial)

def create_queue(job_name, task_index, worker_hosts):
  with tf.device("/job:%s/task:%d" % (job_name, task_index)):
  return tf.FIFOQueue(len(worker_hosts), tf.int32,    shared_name="queue_"+str(job_name)+"_"+str(task_index))

def main(_):
  ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")

# Create a cluster from the parameter server and worker hosts.
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})

# Create and start a server for the local task.
server = tf.train.Server(cluster,
                       job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                       task_index=FLAGS.task_index)

if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":

# Control shutdown of parameter server in queue instead of server.join() function.
queue = create_queue(FLAGS.job_name, FLAGS.task_index, worker_hosts)

with tf.Session(server.target) as sess:
  for i in range(len(worker_hosts)):
    sess.run(queue.dequeue())

 elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":

# Assigns ops to the local worker by default.
with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
    worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
    cluster=cluster)):

  # Import data
  mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)

  # Build Deep MNIST model...
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
  y_conv, keep_prob = deepnn(x)

  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
      tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))

  global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()

  train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy, global_step=global_step)
  correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

# Create queues for all servers participating in the cluster.
queue = create_queue(FLAGS.job_name, FLAGS.task_index, worker_hosts)
queues = []
for i in range(len(ps_hosts)):
  queues.append(create_queue("ps", i, worker_hosts))
for i in range(len(worker_hosts)):
  queues.append(create_queue("worker", i, worker_hosts))

# The StopAtStepHook handles stopping after running given steps.
hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=1000)]

# The MonitoredTrainingSession takes care of session initialization,
# restoring from a checkpoint, saving to a checkpoint, and closing when done
# or an error occurs.
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,
                                       is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                                       checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.log_dir,
                                       hooks=hooks) as mon_sess:
  i = 0
  while not mon_sess.should_stop():
    # Run a training step asynchronously.
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
    if i % 100 == 0:
      train_accuracy = mon_sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={
          x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
      print('global_step %s, task:%d_step %d, training accuracy %g'
            % (tf.train.global_step(mon_sess, global_step), FLAGS.task_index, i, train_accuracy))
    mon_sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
    i = i + 1

# Notification of task completion and wait for task completion of other worker server.
with tf.Session(server.target) as sess:
  for q in queues:
    sess.run(q.enqueue(1))
  for i in range(len(worker_hosts)):
    sess.run(queue.dequeue())

if __name__ == "__main__":
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
 parser.register("type", "bool", lambda v: v.lower() == "true")
 # Flags for defining the tf.train.ClusterSpec
parser.add_argument(
   "--ps_hosts",
   type=str,
   default="",
   help="Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs"
)
 parser.add_argument(
    "--worker_hosts",
    type=str,
    default="",
    help="Comma-separated li^st of hostname:port pairs"
  )
 parser.add_argument(
    "--job_name",
    type=str,
    default="",
    help="One of 'ps', 'worker'"
 )
  # Flags for defining the tf.train.Server
  parser.add_argument(
    "--task_index",
    type=int,
    default=0,
    help="Index of task within the job"
  )
  # Flags for specifying input/output directories
  parser.add_argument(
     "--data_dir",
     type=str,
     default="/home/goel/workspace/mnist/mnist",
     help="Directory for storing input data")

   parser.add_argument(
    "--log_dir",
    type=str,
    default="hdfs://SDL/user/goel/logs",
    help="Directory for train logs")

  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

I am getting the following logs on the screen when I pass "hdfs://SDL/user/goel/logs" to the checkpoint variable in MonitoredTrainingSession API. The program just hangs at this point and does nothing. There are no errors and its not writing anything in hdfs. FYI, I am able to write files into the same hdfs directory using pydoop.

```
 Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/hadoop/tmp
2017-08-23 15:13:43.655845: W tensorflow/core/platform   /cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use  SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-23 15:13:43.655884: W tensorflow/core/platform /cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed  up CPU computations.
2017-08-23 15:13:43.655892: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-23 15:13:43.655899: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-23 15:13:43.665183: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:200] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job ps -> {0 -> localhost:2845}
2017-08-23 15:13:43.665222: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:200] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> localhost:2745}
2017-08-23 15:13:43.667440: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:240] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2745
  Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/hadoop/tmp
  2017-08-23 15:13:44,397 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
 2017-08-23 15:13:45,097 WARN  [main] shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory (DomainSocketFactory.java:<init>(117)) - The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
```

Comment: Could you paste the error message you are getting?

Comment: Hi, I have added the output logs I am getting, although there are no errors but the program does not proceed after starting the server. Is the format of hdfs directory path not the way the API is expecting.